# Winform labels wrong alignment / size

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following layout in my designer.

[image: Designer]

and for some reason, the output is coming out with the font with different sizes and location. I am unsure why or how to fix this.

[image: Output]

I have tried with the different font measurements to see if this is the cause, along with disabling any autosize and autoscale properties for the tables/form with no luck.

has anyone seen this before / know how to resolve it?

thanks

Comment: Is the form dpi-aware?

Comment: forgive me - how do i check this?

Comment: What is the Form's AutoScaleMode ?

Comment: it's now DPI and it's started working - i swear i checked this before and it didnt do anything :/ 
Thanks for the help!